# How could I justify text in a text_box in Prawn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, prawn

Is there a way to justify text in pdf.text_box using the prawn plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Here is where the documentation for text_box is: [Class::Prawn::Document](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/prawn-core/classes/Prawn/Document.html#M000114)

The text box is like most other prawn functions and takes the data and then the options.

```
#text_box(text,options)

pdf.text "Here is some text for this text entry", :size => 16, :align => :left
```

Using the `:align` option is what I think you need.

The Rails Cast did an episode on Prawn that may also be useful.  Check that out [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn).

Comment: It would actually be `:align => :justify`. Editing your answer would go against your intent so I won't edit it, but please do update it =)